# How can I get properties from each one letter amino acid?

Tags: python, proteins

Im using python and wish to get properties from each one letter amino acid?

I mean
M(Met) => Density:1.340, MW:149.21...

The RDkit methods atom.GetSymbol(), atom.GetDegree() permit this and I am looking for an equivalent solution in Python.

Are there any suitable package, for example in Biopython?

Comment: Check `ProteinAnalysis` from `Bio.Seq.Utils.ProtParam` in Biopython.

Comment: RDKit is a Python solution.